# MSI Register for pcie device driver

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling, dma, pci-e

In my project,I want to develop a pcie linux device driver with 32 bits MSI handler.For this purpose I wrote a code like this:

```
        if((pci_resource_flags(dev,i)&IORESOURCE_TYPE_BITS)==IORESOURCE_MEM)
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "memmap1");
            devInfo->resource[i].type=IORESOURCE_MEM;
            devInfo->resource[i].flag=pci_resource_flags(dev,i);
            devInfo->resource[i].RegsLength=(u32)pci_resource_len(dev,i);
            devInfo->resource[i].RegsBase=ioremap_nocache(pci_resource_start(dev,i),pci_resource_len(dev,i));
            devInfo->resource[i].PhysBase.QuadPart=(u64)pci_resource_start(dev,i);

            if(devInfo->resource[i].RegsBase==NULL)
            {
                printk(KERN_ERR "pci_ioremap_bar da hata olustu!\n");
                return -ENOMEM;
            }
            printk(KERN_INFO "Birinci bar icin type:%d",devInfo->resource[0].type);
            printk(KERN_INFO "Birinci bar icin register length:%d",devInfo->resource[0].RegsLength);


        }
    if(pci_enable_msi(dev))
    {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "MSI enable basarisiz oldu\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(request_irq(dev->irq, irq_handler, 0,"bbn_fpga", NULL))
    {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "MSI register edilemiyor\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    devInfo->flag=0;
    printk(KERN_INFO "iowrite icerisine giriyorum");
    iowrite32((u32) 0x80000000,&devInfo->resource[0].RegsBase);


    if(devInfo->flag==0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Interrupt\n");
        return -1;
    }

    static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "(irq_handler):  Called\n");
        return IRQ_HANDLED;
    }
```

Here,I wrote 80000000 to registery base to create a MSI interrupt although it does not work.From here how can I take the 32-bits of MSI interrupt?

Comment: Of course it will not work. You missed completely how it's **supposed to work**. In case of Linux it's hidden in the PCI core implementation. The MSI vector is defined by platform. Please, read any of PCI architecture related book.

Answer (score 0):

MSI interrupts are generated by -

```
PCIe endpoint generating a memory write transaction to the specified
address in MSI capability register
```

So a memory write from CPU to the MSI address is not going to do anything. It has to be a memory write transaction from the PCIe endpoint.